# Do the draw abilities of Kor Spiritdancer and Mesa Enchantress stack?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Suppose I have both [Kor Spiritdancer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kor%20Spiritdancer) and [Mesa Enchantress](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mesa%20Enchantress) under my control. They have two similar abilities:

> **Kor Spiritdancer:** Whenever you cast an Aura spell, you may draw a card.

> **Mesa Enchantress:** Whenever you cast an enchantment spell, you may draw a card.

If I now cast an **Enchantment — Aura** card, do I draw two cards or one?

Comment: If X says do A if Z and Y says do B if z, if Zz, do I do A and B?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Note that you can auto-link to MTG cards by using [mtg:cardname].

Comment: The possible duplicate I proposed has different cards, but it's basically the same situation: you have two creatures each with a triggered ability, and they both trigger.

Comment: Disagree on duplicate. The answer is the same, but the question is not, which is the definition of duplicate. Just because a question has the same answer as another because they both can be answered by the same rule does not make it a duplicate, because that's the point of rules: cover a lot of different situations under one rule.

Comment: @Hackworth The definition of duplicate is definitely not just identical questions.  We don't want to have a question for every single possible combination of cards that'd make two things trigger at once, for example, so it's reasonable to deduplicate some things like this. So maybe this particular case is too different to be duplicates, maybe not, but don't just think of it as questions having to be identical.

Comment: I agree with Hackworth's philosophy, but I also think these questions are duplicates. The root of both questions is **"Do the triggered abilities of *[arbitrary object or collection of objects]* stack?"**

Comment: There are no real exceptions for the question asked here, but for the general case I can think of at least one or two *potential* exceptions and with the number of possible card combinations available I imagine answering such a general question would be painful.

Comment: I would suggest such a question might be too broad.

Comment: @Isaac I'd love to hear about the potential exceptions where triggered abilities don't stack. Want to join the [site's chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49/board-and-card-games) and discuss?

Comment: @Jefromi I think the linked question is not a duplicate. That one is asking about identical ability-granting abilities giving creatures duplicate abilities. This one is asking about identical triggered abilities triggering.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Ugh, I guess I picked the wrong one. The right one is probably: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/15036/do-triggered-effects-stack (though it's quite possible we could do a much better job writing a more generic question and more clear answer now)

Comment: That one is a lot better

Comment: The thing I see with this question is that its not even two cards with the same trigger... one is specific to Auras and the other to Enchantments all together. When the Aura is played it would trigger the specific aura ability and then trigger the ability for being an Enchantment. It would be a duplicate if it was the same card that gave the same effect - as the question noted is "can two of said cards stack one ability trigger twice" not two different cards that trigger for different things... However it does match as a duplicate of "Do triggered abilities stack."

Answer (score 3):

You can draw 2 cards. When you cast an Aura spell, then 2 separate triggered abilities will trigger. You choose the order in which to put them on the stack (the order doesn't matter in this case), and then you will have 2 separate instances of "you may draw a card" on the stack, which will resolve one at a time.

Comment: thanks a lot :) ... Same (draw 2 cards) with two spiritdancers or two Mesa's ...am i right?

Comment: @Roman Right.  2 separate sources with 2 separate triggered abilities that each go on the stack and each resolve separately.